# Creating Mutiple Pivot Tables from single data source

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table on a new sheet. Additionally, I would like to create another call to create another different pivot table using the same data from the first data sheet.

having trouble with the macro below. I think it is a small error, but can't figure it out.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim FinalRow            As Long
    Dim DataSheet           As String
    Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
    Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
    Dim DataRng             As Range
    Dim TableDest           As Range
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet

    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    DataSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    'set data range for Pivot Table -- ' conversion of R1C1:R & FinalRow & C15
     Set DataRng = Sheets(DataSheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, 15)) 

    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.Name = "Travel Payment Data by Employee"

    'set range for Pivot table placement -- Conversion of R1C1
    Set TableDest = Sheets("Travel Payment Data by Employee").Cells(1, 1)

    Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, DataRng, xlPivotTableVersion15)

    'check if "PivotTable4" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)
    Set PvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Travel Payment Data by Employee").PivotTables("PivotTable4")

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Security Org")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Month")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Budget Org")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Vendor Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 4
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Year")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 5
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Year")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    PvtTbl.AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Dollar Amount"), "Sum of Dollar Amount", xlSum

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you attempt a second Pivot Table object? And where does *PivotTable2* come from?

Comment: I think that was a typo and should have been PivotTable4. for the name of the pivot table. I haven't attempted the second pivot table object. Right now I am trying to pull data dynamically to a new sheet. I imagine I can add a call to run a similar code for a new sheet. My issue comes up at Set PvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(DataSheet).PivotTables("PivotTable4"). Runtime error 1004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following adjustment with a subroutine calling a function, passing in new worksheet names for new identical pivot tables. If you do not intend identical pivots, adjust them in code conditionally by sheet name or copies of function. The main changes from your code are as follows:

1. ACTIVE SHEET: Remove the need to search `ActiveSheet.Name` as adding more worksheets will alter active sheets. Simply hard-code or pass as parameter the data source.
2. OBJECT CHECK: You need to check if Worksheet exits and PivotTable exists. For these, you will need to iterate through all current such objects  and conditionally set worksheet, pivot table objects (see `For...Next` loops and `If ... Is Nothing` checks).
3. For PivotField, since *Dollar Amounts* will exist in Pivot Table data source but not necessarily display, iterating through all of them might not work like above. So conditionally add only if does not error out see `On Resume Next` handle.

**VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunPivots()
    Call BuildPivot("Travel Payment Data by Employee")
    Call BuildPivot("Other Worksheet")
    Call BuildPivot("Still More Worksheet")
End Sub

Function BuildPivot(paramSheet As String)
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim FinalRow            As Long
    Dim DataSheet           As String
    Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
    Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
    Dim PvtFld              As PivotField
    Dim DataRng             As Range
    Dim TableDest           As Range
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet

    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    DataSheet = "DataSourceWorksheet"    
    ' set data range for Pivot Table
     Set DataRng = Sheets(DataSheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, 15))

    ' check if worksheet exists
    Dim currws As Worksheet
    For Each currws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If currws.Name = paramSheet Then
            Set ws = Worksheets(paramSheet)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currws

    ' create new worksheet if does not exist
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add
        ws.Name = paramSheet
    End If

    ' set range for Pivot table placement
    Set TableDest = Sheets(paramSheet).Cells(1, 1)

    ' create pivot cache
    Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
              SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
              SourceData:=DataRng, _
              Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

    'check if "PivotTable4" Pivot Table exists            
    Dim currpvt As PivotTable
    For Each currpvt In ws.PivotTables
        If currpvt.Name = "PivotTable4" Then
            Set PvtTbl = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable4")
            Exit For   
        End If
    Next currpvt

    ' create new pivot table if does not exist
    If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then
        Set PvtTbl = PvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
            TableDestination:=TableDest, _
            TableName:="PivotTable4")
    End If

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Security Org")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Month")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Budget Org")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Vendor Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 4
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Year")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 5
    End With
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Year")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    ' Add data field if does not exist
    On Error Resume Next
    PvtTbl.AddDataField PvtTbl.PivotFields("Dollar Amount"), "Sum of Dollar Amount", xlSum

    Exit Function

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Option Explicit

Public Sub RunPivots()
    Call BuildPivot("Travel Payment Data by Employee")
    Call BuildPivot("Travel Payment Data by Acct Dim")

Comment: Disregard above. Your code works, but now I am trying to put the sub in for a new pivot table with different  parameters. You are saying add a new function after the exit function and specify the name of the sheet?

Comment: Do you have question? Yes go ahead and implement specific worksheets as needed.

Comment: Simply create a new function similar to this one but change data source and/or pivot fields at end.

Comment: Sorry, but the second function isn't being called. It just says application defined or object defined error. I already changed the pivot fields, the data source is staying the same. I renamed the function and call "BuildPivot2" because i was getting an error that was due to the same call name being used.

Comment: How can I help as I don't see such a function? Just carefully check what you changed from this version.